# How to get all product details and sku using REST API in magento 2? using integration

Tags: magento2, rest-api

```
<?php
$productUrl='http:yourlUrl/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20';

$ch = curl_init($productUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token"
    )
);
$productList = curl_exec($ch);
$err      = curl_error($ch);
$products = json_decode($productList);
echo '<pre>';print_r($products );
curl_close($ch);
```

> Where to place this code in my module Directory?

**Any help would Appreciate**

Comment: Place this code in you module controller file

Comment: can you tell me the specific directory fot this?